# JBOSS 7.1: Adding Primefaces support prevents deployment

Tags: eclipse, primefaces, jboss7.x

When I add the PrimeFaces jar to a typical Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
15:44:40,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found FileUploadTest.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called FileUploadTest.war.dodeploy
15:44:40,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "FileUploadTest.war"
15:44:40,339 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."FileUploadTest.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."FileUploadTest.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "FileUploadTest.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter from [Module "deployment.FileUploadTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    ... 7 more

15:44:40,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "FileUploadTest.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"FileUploadTest.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"FileUploadTest.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"FileUploadTest.war\""}}
15:44:40,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."FileUploadTest.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."FileUploadTest.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "FileUploadTest.war"

15:44:40,402 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"FileUploadTest.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"FileUploadTest.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"FileUploadTest.war\""}}}}
15:44:40,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment FileUploadTest.war in 9ms
```

I've added `commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar` as well as `commons-io-1.4.jar`. No idea what the problem could be. I've also referred to [Error deploying Primefaces application on JBoss 7.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020447/error-deploying-primefaces-application-on-jboss-7-1-0) and tried adding the "context-param" value to web.xml but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the PrimeFaces dependency. Could you add the structure of your WAR?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It's a standard eclipse Dynamic Web Project. I've only added the PrimeFaces.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar as well as commons-io-1.4.jar to the build path. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was adding the JAR files(primefaces, commons-fileupload-1.2.1 and commons-io-1.4) by doing

`Right click project->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Java Build Path` and adding the JAR's there.

I needed to add them in `...->Configure Build Path->Deployment Assembly` instead.

I guess I need to learn how to Eclipse :)

Comment: Or just use a build tool like Maven :-)