# How to use JSF 2.1.14 Mojarra, Servlet 3.0 and EL 2.2 in JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final?

Tags: java, jsf-2, el, jboss7.x, servlet-3.0

In my application I want to use JSF 2.1.14 Mojarra with Servlet 3.0 and EL 2.2. The server is JBoss-AS-7.1.1-Final.

Now that I have added these dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

These jars are in the /WEB-INF/lib. After deploying the application in the container in the console I can see a log:

```
18:15:02,278 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-12) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/ActivityDatabase'
```

This clearly means that JBoss is not using the JSF version that I have placed within the war file.

After Googling and searching other SO threads I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028881/576758), that I need to tell the container to use the JSF bundles provided in the WAR file. So I have added:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my web.xml. After that when I deployed the war, at the time of deployment I am getting Exception:

```
18:39:57,665 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
        at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:808) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:349) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        ... 9 more

18:39:57,696 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ActivityDatabase]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvi
der is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:290) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
        at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:808) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:349) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        ... 9 more

18:39:57,743 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Error listenerStart
18:39:57,758 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Context [/ActivityDatabase] startup failed due to previous errors
18:39:57,758 SEVERE [javax.faces] (MSC service thread 1-8) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
18:39:57,758 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1010) [jsf-api-2.1.14.jar:2.1]
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:342) [jsf-api-2.1.14.jar:2.1]
        at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:136) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.1.14.jar:2.1.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

18:39:57,805 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

18:39:57,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:39:57,836 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4446ms - Started 444 of 523 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
18:39:58,039 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ActivityDatabase.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
18:39:58,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ActivityDatabase.war in 145ms
18:39:58,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

18:39:58,179 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ActivityDatabase: JBAS01
8040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

I have also tried to exclude the jsf module from jboss-deployment-structure.xml as:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But no luck, same error. I am still searching web for a solution but nothing is working. Also I am not sure whether or not JBoss is using Servlet 3.0 and EL 2.2. Although I have specified `version="3.0"` in web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    ---

</web-app>
```

Any suggestion will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider

This is a bug which was discovered for first time in JBoss 7.1.0 and is fixed in JBoss 7.1.3, see also [JBoss AS 7 issue 3940](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3940).

So, upgrading to at least 7.1.3 should fix it.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I was practically waiting for you. :-). Do you know from where I can download it? I don't find it! Is it downloadable?

Comment: 7.1.3 is EAP only. You'd need to build from this git repo yourself: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as You can alternatively also try a 7.x nightly build (which is 7.2 alpha at this moment) https://community.jboss.org/thread/167590

Comment: Thanks for these links. Could you please tell me, how can I know if my application is using the servlet 3.0 and el 2.2 or not?

Comment: JBoss >=6 implements Servlet 3.0, so you're OK. Easy evidence/test is being able to create, compile and run a `@WebServlet` class without any line of `web.xml` configuration.

Comment: So I don't need to include those jars in the lib. I have found that jboss modules has jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar. I have already used @WebFilter

Comment: You should definitely not have servlet-container specific libraries ending up in the `/WEB-INF/lib` of the built WAR. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706 I don't do Maven (yet), but if I am correct, you should mark those servletcontainer-provided dependencies as `<provided>` in your pom.